# C# if this else if that syntax

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a question called "Q2" it has 5 options, I am using the code below to mask some of the options depending on the "Culture". The `if` part of the code works but the `else` part doesn't.

```
if(this.Culture == "hu-HU"| this.Culture == "tr-TR")
{
    Hide(Q2,3);
}
else if (this.Culture == "gb-GB")
{
    Hide(Q2,3,4,5);
}
```

In plain English, it should **test if culture is x or y then hide (q2, 3), if culture is that then hide (q2, 3, 4, 5)**

Comment: Probably need to post Hide code.... but this question is not really all that greatly posted.

Comment: Are you sure it is not `en-GB`?

Comment: What is the Culture value where you have found it is not working

Comment: @RobScott No you don't you only need that if you want it to short circuit when the first expression is true and not evaluate the second.

Comment: There is no culture `gb-GB`. For [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx).

Comment: Turns out it was "en-GB"! so sorry guys.

Comment: watch out, `|` does not do what you think it is doing. You need `||` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the string you're validating against, it might be `en-GB` rather then `gb-GB`.
You can check codes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233968.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just change `"gb-GB"` to `"en-GB"`

Here is a list of all culture codes

[Table of Language Culture Names, Codes, and ISO Values Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)